# Python - TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable in simple fucntion

Tags: python, int, typeerror

```
a = -7
b = 1
print(abs(a-b))
print(abs(a+b))
sum(a,b)
def sum(i,j):
  return (abs(i+j) == 6) or (abs(i-j) == 6)
```

The error states that 'int cannot be iterable'

Comment: call `sum()` after the function

Comment: There is a built-in `sum()` function. That works like this: `sum([4,5])`. Please do not override built-in functions unless you have a good reason to do so

Comment: Please share the **entire** error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the Comments above, you need to call your function *after* you define it. In addition, also as stated in the Comments above, it's not a best practice to name your function using the same name as a built-in function (i.e., sum).

Renaming your function to *my_sum*, this should work:

```
def my_sum(i,j):
  return (abs(i+j) == 6) or (abs(i-j) == 6)

a = -7
b = 1
print(abs(a-b))
print(abs(a+b))
print(my_sum(a,b))
```